# Pandas quoting param

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to understand exactly what the `quoting` and `doublequote` mean within the pandas.read_csv module. Let's suppose I have the following data:

```
['name' ,'age' ,'position']
['tom', 14, 'vp']
['jared', 100, 'head, sales']
```

pandas has three `quoting` options:

1. QUOTE_MINIMAL (0) [default]
2. QUOTE_ALL (1)
3. QUOTE_NONNUMERIC (2)
4. QUOTE_NONE (3)

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

If the `quotechar` is `"`, how would the above four parameters interpret the above data?

Comment: Have you tried running each to see what actually happens?

Comment: @G.Anderson thanks, I updated an answer for this as well.

Answer (score 4):

You could try doing something like this to test with the `csv` writer:

```
import csv
DATA = [
    ['name' ,'age' ,'position'],
    ['tom', 14, 'vp'],
    ['jared', 100, 'head, sales'],
]

with open('test_min.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in DATA:
        writer.writerow(row)

with open('test_all.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for row in DATA:
        writer.writerow(row)

with open('test_nonnumeric.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for row in DATA:
        writer.writerow(row)

with open('test_quotenone.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in DATA:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Here is what you'll see:

1. QUOTE_NONE

   `name,age,position
   tom,14,vp`

   **Notes**: invalid output, will need an escape character set.
2. QUOTE_NONNUMERIC

   `"name","age","position"
   "tom",14,"vp"
   "jared",100,"head, sales"`

   **Notes**: notice that `14` and `100` are not escaped.
3. QUOTE_MINIMUM

   `name,age,position
   tom,14,vp
   jared,100,"head, sales"`

   **Notes**: only `head, sales` will be quoted, as it is the offending field.
4. QUOTE_ALL

   `"name","age","position"
   "tom","14","vp"
   "jared","100","head, sales"`

   **Notes**: everything is quoted, regardless of type.